# Directory 'uploads/' for the site filebrowser.filebrowser does not exist

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

I've managed to use django-filebrowser to upload file via TinyMCE based on this documentation:
http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

I've put reference to `tiny_mce.js` and `tinymce_setup.js` from `Grappeli` folder to my template,now `TinyMCE` works.

but when testing `filebrowser` with this command:`python manage.py test filebrowser` I get this error:`Directory 'uploads/' for the site filebrowser.filebrowser does not exist.` ,of course all of project throw this error.I searched this error in google but no proper result!

Note:I've gotten Grappeli worked already.

what do U think?

Comment: Do you have `uploads` dir in your MEDIA_ROOT? :)

Comment: yes I have,I don't know why It has this error

Comment: Please show us the full stacktrace.

Comment: However I alreadey had an uploads folder,when I made another uploads folder inside that my problem was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

For those having problems with filebrowser setup, here is what is required to set it up after you install it.

Add it to your INSTALLED_APPS as:

```
'filebrowser',
```

In your urls.py master file, add the file browser pattern:

```
from filebrowser.sites import site

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),
   ....)
```

Then make sure you have your MEDIA_ROOT set and that by default the uploads/ folder exists in the MEDIA_ROOT.  You can change the uploads folder by settting FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY to something different:

```
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = 'filebrowser_uploads/'
```

Then I usually run a test and see if anything is broken and why:

```
python manage.py test filebrowser
```

I don't know why the setup doesn't create the default directory for it if MEDIA_ROOT exists. Instead it checks if MEDIA_ROOT + FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY exist and it fails if it doesn't.  More on this in the [quick start guide](http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html).